# Creating an Array filled with Random doubles and finding the Maximum and Average

Tags: java

I need help with this program, I need to

1. Ask the user to input rows and column sizes using scanner
2. if the column size is greater than 4+5, they need to re-enter it
3. I need to fill all the array elements with doubles in range of 4.0, 11.0 by using random object
4. Find the above array and call two methods,
5. Method one, I need to find and print the largest sum of columns in the 2D array
6. Method two, I need to find the average of all elements in the array and return the average value.

Here's my code, it sort of accomplishes it, but it's also sort of messed up and I'm confused.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter row size");
    int rows = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter column size");
    int columns = input.nextInt();
    double n = 4.0;
    if (columns < n+5.0){
    } else{
        System.out.println("The column size is too large, please enter a smaller integer");
    }
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];
    for(int a = 0; a<rows; a++)
        for(int b = 0; b<columns; b++)
            array[a][b] = rand.nextInt(11-4) + 4;

    for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        double sum = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j<columns; j++){
            sum += array[j][i];
            sum2 = sum2 + array[i][j];
             System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
        }           

        double average = sum/array.length;
        System.out.println("largest sum of the columns is " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average of all elements in the array is " + average);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: _but it's also sort of messed up and I'm confused_ What's messed up? What do you expect and what happens?

Comment: It prints everything three times for some reason, instead of one Array with the columns and rows I entered

Comment: It print's it like that because you have given all the println statements inside for loops. Move all those statements outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use while loops to check if the input is even a valid integer and then if the columns count is larger than 4 + 5 ( i just assumed 9 ). I made the program flow a bit more structured and made a neat output. Basically you just would have to move the System.out.println out of the Loop like @Codebender pointed out.

```
package array;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayUtil {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int columns;
    int rows;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter row size :");

    while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid Number! Try again.");
        input.next();
    }

    rows = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter column size :");

    while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid Number! Try again.");
        input.next();
    }

    columns = input.nextInt();

    while (columns > 9) {
        System.out.println("The column size is too large, please enter a smaller integer!");
        columns = input.nextInt();
    }



    Random rand = new Random();

    int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];
    for (int a = 0; a < rows; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < columns; b++) {
            array[a][b] = rand.nextInt(11 - 4) + 4;
        }
    }

    for (int[] arr : array) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i : arr) {
            sb.append("[");
            sb.append(i);
            sb.append("]");
        }
        System.out.println("Array :" + sb.toString());
        System.out.println("Average : " + average(arr));
        System.out.println("Max : " + max(arr));
    }

}

public static double average(int[] values) {
    double d = 0;

    for (double value : values) {
        d = value + d;
    }

    return (d / values.length);
}

public static double max(int[] values) {
    double d = 0;
    for (double value : values) {
        if (value > d) {
            d = value;
        }
    }

    return d;
}

}
```